# StandardSetControllers Save Not Working

Tags: apex, standardsetcontroller

The `save` method on the `StandardSetController` is not working as I expect.

I have a controller to update a list of custom objects. I have a vf page with a text box for the update and a <kbd>Submit</kbd> button to make the update.

```
public class ClaimExpenseController    
{  
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {    
        get { 
            setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([
                Select tc9_ti__Title__c from tc9_ti__Expense__c
            ]));  
            return setCon;  
        }  
        set;  
    }  
    public List<tc9_ti__Expense__c> getExpenseList()  
    {
        return (List<tc9_ti__Expense__c>)setCon.getRecords();  
    }  
    public PageReference submitExpenses()  
    {
        setcon.save();    
        return null;
    }  
}
```

In vf, I have a repeat

```
<apex:repeat value="{!expenseList}" var="exp">    
    <input type = "text" style = 'width:100%' value="{!exp.tc9_ti__Title__c}"/>
</apex:repeat>  
<button class = 'button' onclick="submitExpJS();" style = 'width:150px; height:45px'>Submit </button>    
<apex:actionFunction name="submitExpJS" 
    action="{!submitExpenses}" reRender="messagePanel"/>
```

My changes to the list are not getting saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help someone who might be stuck with the same issue, this was fixed by using                                                         <apex:inputfield value="{!exp. tc9_ti__Title__c}"/> ..the below tag also worked!
<apex:inputText value="{!exp. tc9_ti__Title__c}"/>

Answer (score 3):

1. You should lazy-load your `StandardSetController` getter.
2. Your `submitExpenses` method should not even compile, as you do not have any `return` statement.
3. You should add error handling to your code.
4. The `apex:inputField` tag will bind to fields on your records.

---

**Lazy Load Pattern**

```
public ApexPages.StandardSetController controller
{
    get
    {
        if (controller == null)
        { // this block is where the magic happens
            controller = new ApexPages.StandardSetController([/*query*/]);
        }
        return controller
    }
    private set;
    // do you really want your page setting this property?
    // use private set unless you actually *need* it posted back
}
```

---

**Method**

I believe you have to select the records to get the default `save` method to work. Make sure you add an `apex:pageMessages` tag to your page, and rerender it from your `actionFunction`.

```
public PageReference submitExpenses()
{
    PageReference redirect;
    try
    {
        controller.setSelected(controller.getRecords());
        redirect = controller.save();
    }
    catch (DmlException dmx)
    {
        ApexPages.addMessages(dmx);
        return null;
        // don't redirect, or you can't rerender the pageMessages!
    }
    return redirect;
}
```

---

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm):

> `apex:inputField`
>
> An HTML input element for a value that corresponds to a field on a Salesforce object. The  component respects the attributes of the associated field, including whether the field is required or unique, and the user interface widget to display to get input from the user. For exam

Comment: last line sb `return redirect` I believe

Comment: I had to use  <apex:inputfield value="{!exp. tc9_ti__Title__c}"/>     instead of <input type = "text" value="{!exp.tc9_ti__Title__c}"/> .. I am not sure if this is documented anywhere!

Comment: @ShaliniMendu Added a little detail there. Not sure why `input` doesn't work, but `inputField` was actually built for that purpose.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, I knew apex:inputField respects all the validations, etc., but since it renders as <input type="text"> finally on the page, i thought it would understand to set the values too, which it did not. Moreover, the funny bit is, the list renders the values correctly, which means it knows how to get the values from the controller but it doesn't know how to set the values back into the controller which is really strange, one more unexplainable limitations of SF :( i guess which has to be just remembered :(..

Comment: Good learning experience! :)

Comment: <apex:inputText> also works! it just doesn't like the HTML input text :)

Comment: @AdrianLarson Standardsetcontroller save method returns a pagereference. It does not throw error. So how would it enter in catch block?